# deadlock with socket

Tags: c, networking

I have written this program to send and receive packets from ipv6 on eth0:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main() {

    int sock,i;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *address;
    struct protoent *proto;
    struct ifreq ethreq, Interface, Interface1;
    unsigned char buffer[2048];
    unsigned char tbuff[2048];
    unsigned char *iphead, *ethhead,*phead;
    static const uint8_t mys6_addr[16]={0x54,0x04,0x20,0x49,0x0e,0x40,0xc7,0x03,0xa0};

    //open socket for receive ipv6 packet 
    sock=socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW,255);
    //control error
    if(sock<0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    strncpy(ethreq.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(sock,SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ethreq) == -1) {
        perror("ioctl");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);
    }

    ethreq.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ethreq) == -1) {
        perror("ioctl");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);
    }

    //bind to sock with eth0 
    memset(&Interface, 0, sizeof(Interface));
    strncpy(Interface.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ);
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &Interface, sizeof(Interface))<0)
        close(sock);

    //open the RAW socket for sendto
    int s = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, 255);
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6; 
    memset(&sin6,0,sizeof(sin6));
    sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sin6.sin6_port = htons(0);
    memcpy(sin6.sin6_addr.s6_addr, mys6_addr, sizeof(mys6_addr));
    //bind the sock descriptor with eth0
    memset(&Interface1, 0, sizeof(Interface1));
    strncpy(Interface1.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ);
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &Interface1, sizeof(Interface1)) < 0) {
        close(s);
    }
    while (1) {

        printf("----------------------\n");
        i = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        printf("%d bytes read\n", i);
        // check header size: Ethernet = 14, IP = 20, TCP = 8 (sum = 42)
        i=43;
        if (i < 42) {
            perror("recvfrom():");
            printf("Incomplete packet (errno is %d)\n", errno);
            close(sock);
            exit(0);
        }
        phead = buffer + 14; // (skip ethernet  header)
        memcpy(tbuff,phead,i-14); 
        iphead=tbuff;
        if (*iphead == 0x45) {
            int ptrindex= iphead[9];
            switch(ptrindex){

            case 1:
            printf("The transport protocl is:ICMP\n");
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("The transport protol is:IGMP\n");
            break;
            case 6:
            printf("The transport protocol is:TCP\n");
            break;
            case 17:
            printf("The transport protocol is:UDP\n");
            break;
            case 103:
            printf("The transport protocol is:PIM\n"); 
            break; 
            default:
            printf("The transport protocol is:%d\n",iphead[9]);
        }           
        //printf("%d",*ptrindex);
        // printf("\n The transport protocol is :%u\n",iphead[9]); 
        printf("Source Address: %d.%d.%d.%d, Port: %d\n",
        iphead[12], iphead[13], iphead[14], iphead[15], (iphead[20] << 8) + iphead[21]);
        printf("Dest Address: %d.%d.%d.%d, Port: %d\n",
        iphead[16], iphead[17], iphead[18], iphead[19], (iphead[22] << 8) + iphead[23]);


        /* if(sendto(s,tbuff,i-14,0,(struct sockaddr_in6 *)&sin6,sizeof(sin6))<0)
        printf("error\n"); */

        if(send(s,tbuff,i-14,0)<0) {
            printf("error\n");

        } else {
            printf("\nThe received packet is send\n");
        }

        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        memset(tbuff,0,sizeof(tbuff));

        } else{
            printf("The non ip had received");
        }

    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

The most of code is part of a question that i have read, but now i don't remembert what was. This program go in deadlock at printf("----------------\n"). Why? Can you help me?

Comment: Two things.  1)  You may want to look into separating the logic of your program into different methods, to make it more readable, and easy to debug.  2)  We can't read your code for you; please narrow it down to a simple, short, self-contained, [compilable] example.  See [sscce.org](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock is a circular chain of locks. There are no locks here, and therefore no deadlock either. All that is happening is that `recv()` is blocking waiting for input to arrive.